# Not sure if I screwd up my hard drive using New Simple Volume

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I was trying to get an external hard drive to work on my windows which works on my Mac. However, the folder simply does not show up.

Upon some googling, I used this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdE9H7P4HnA to help me get the hard drive to work on my windows pc. I followed the exact same steps(Computer Management --> Click on the unallocated disk --> Right Click and clicked on New Simple Volume --> Pressed Next till the end of the process)and to my horror it worked but with an empty folder called New Volume!

Fearing I deleted the data of the hard drive, I put it back on my macbook and I see that there are now 2 folders from in hard disk, New Volume and the old folder I used to have with all the information I had(Thank God!).

My macbook is about to die as I spilled water onto it. Just wondering if my old folder in my hard drive will be lost due to the rubbish I did with that New Simple Volume on Windows. If I bought a new MacBook and plug in that hard drive, will I be able to see that old folder again?

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: You really need to **tell** us exactly what you did, not expect us to watch through some random youtube video.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry for the lack of clarification and thanks for pointing out what I should do instead. Pretty new around here. Hope the updated post clarifies my question. Thanks.

Comment: OK, sounds like you managed to find a bit of 'spare' disk to make a new volume on... however, what you are going to need is some utility which will enable your Win machine to read/write HFS volumes. Windows can't read Mac disks by default.

Comment: The first thing to do with your valuable information, before the MacBook dies, is copy it to another disk so that you have a backup of it in case anything goes wrong.